# Array to string conversion error rendering a fixed date

Tags: php, symfony, twig

An entity's add date is assigned when it is created and therefore cannot be edited.  If the add date is rendered on the entity's edit form with `{{ form.addDate.vars.value|date('m/d/Y') }}` the error

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Notice: Array to string conversion")...

is thrown.

It is possible to work around this with

```
{% set added = form.addDate.vars.value %}
Added {{ added.month~'/'~added.day~'/'~added.year }}
```

But I wonder if I missed something.  Does the documentation somewhere address this?

Comment: can you give a try at this `{{ form.vars.value.addDate|date('m/d/Y') }}`

Comment: @Matteo That does the trick. Looks like a form of dyslexia struck me!  I even found this in the docs.  I'll accept this as a solution if you like.

Comment: Background info: `form.addDate` is another form with (by default) 3 select fields, that's why it is an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try access directly from the main form instead access from the subform field as follow:

```
{{ form.vars.value.addDate|date('m/d/Y') }}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Yes it helps.  Thanks.